# Count number of times a number 1,2, or 3 is displayed in a table

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a word document with four tables. The top table summarises data within the other three tables.Table A,B, and C

The summary table has four rows each row is the name of a table and five columns.
*Severity 1* , *Severity 2*, *Severity 3*, *Total severities*, *Table Name*

Within each table (Table A,B, C) there is a column named *Severity* it contains levels of severity, numbered 1,2, or 3

I am trying to find a macro which would count the number of 1,2,3 in the severity column for each table in the three tables and enter the information in the summary table.

Comment: You don't need a macro for this - all you need is some suitably-coded formula fields and bookmarks. Not only that but, if you use formfields for the data entry, the field calculations can be made to auto-update.

Comment: Does anyone know how I can count only if it has a number, e.g if number 1 and 2 is in the column only to count the number of 2s?  I have a general count {{ =COUNT(table_A C:C)}} - but cant work out how to specify

Comment: You need to test the contents of each cell individually. For example: {={IF{table_A C1}= 2 1 0}+{IF{table_A C2}= 2 1 0}+{IF{table_A C3}= 2 1 0} \# 0}

Comment: Thanks, thats a shame, as the table changes....  so could be longer or shorter each month. I don't want to have to update these fields every time.

Answer (score 0):

In that case, you could use a macro like:

```
Sub Demo()
Dim t As Long, r As Long, x As Long, y As Long, z As Long
With ActiveDocument
  For t = 2 To .Tables.Count
    x = 0: y = 0: z = 0
    With .Tables(t)
      For r = 1 To .Rows.Count
        Select Case Split(.Cell(t, 3).Range.Text, vbCr)(0)
          Case 1: x = x + 1
          Case 2: y = y + 1
          Case 3: z = z + 1
        End Select
      Next
    End With
    With .Tables(1)
      .Cell(t + 1, 1).Range.Text = x
      .Cell(t + 1, 2).Range.Text = y
      .Cell(t + 1, 3).Range.Text = z
      .Cell(t + 1, 4).Range.Text = x + y + z
    End With
  Next
End With
End Sub
```